# JList and JScrollPane don't respond/are inaccessible

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to implement a basic GUI where a user can move objects from one JList to another. The JLists should be contained within a ScrollPane so size is not an issue. Basic functionality is good, items will move and remove with button presses. However, the JList and JScrollPane that items are added to will display correctly and detect if a ScrollBar is necessary but do not interact AT ALL with the user for some reason. The user cannot select from the JList nor scroll the ScrollPane. Rough idea of the code below;

```
public void createJList(Type[] dataToList){
    someScrollPane = new JScrollPane(); //someScrollPane is private global
    someScrollPane.setBounds(numbers here);
    this.add(someScrollPane); //this is a custom frame class
    aList = new JList<Type>(dataToList);
    someScrollPane.setViewportView(aList);
```

This is a rough idea. I also add a listener at some stage but since the scrollpane isn't working either I may as well leave that for later. I use this code for both the working and non-responsive JLists and ScrollPanes exactly the same.

Of note, I call this method everytime the list I want to display is changed. I'm thinking maybe because the JList and ScrollPane keep getting created, something is broken?

Comment: Avoid using setBounds() and null layouts

Comment: I understand that for proper implementation I should be doing so, but this is entry level Java. I'm just trying to get anything functioning the way I want.

Comment: *"This is a rough idea"* - I suggest you make a runnable example which demonstrates your problem